# React-Router will not load component on direct refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm facing a wierd bug for the below router spec

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={AppContainer}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        <Route path="projects" component={ProjectContainer} />
        <Route path="projects/new" component={newProject} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,document.getElementById('app')
```

i'm able to navigate to `/` and `/projects` by directly entering the url in the browser. however it does not work for `/projects/new`. the page is just blank (not even the standard `cannot GET /projects/new`. I can only navigate to the url by navigating from `/projects` or `/` pages.

My historyApifallback in webpack is set to true. Where am i going wrong?

**Edit: this is the below console.log on loading /projects/new**

```
new:8 GET http://localhost:8080/projects/styles.css 
new:18 GET http://localhost:8080/projects/bundle.js
```

my index.html seems to be looking for the js and css files in /parent while it should be located in root

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <script src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: do you get any output in the console when navigating to `/projects/new`? If so, please edit your question and add the error/warning.

Comment: included the console.log ... it looks like somethings wrong with webpack .. ill look into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<script>` tags `src` attribute, put a slash in the front (e.g `/bundle.js`). That way it will always use root as the base path.

Comment: HA! This was my issue. Thanks!